# Excel Userform textbox value into comment

Tags: vba, excel, macros, userform

I would like to convert the value input in a userform textbox into a comment. So far I have not found anything that works. Currently I have this

Cells(emptyRow, 8).AddComment.Text = NotesTextBox.Value

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text can just be passed as a parameter to `.AddComment`:

```
Cells(emptyRow, 8).AddComment NotesTextBox.Value
```

Comment: It works! Do you know how I would incorporate Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True

Comment: @D.Cruz - `AddComment` returns a `Comment` object.  Just grab a reference and work with it's `.Shape`.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is possible... The problem with your question is that this is a sufficient answer.  You might explain more your problem. Correct syntax is:

```
Cells(emptyRow, 8).AddComment NotesTextBox.Value
```